# Exibir um horário TimeSpan formatado

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, timespan

Tenho duas variáveis:

```
        TimeSpan horaI = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);
        TimeSpan horaF = new TimeSpan(22, 00, 00);
```

Preciso apresentar elas na tela da seguinte maneira 10:00 e 22:00.
Porém, não estou conseguindo.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
var horaI = new TimeSpan(10, 00, 00);

var horaFormatada = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm}", horaI);
```

Claro que existem várias outras maneiras de se fazer isso.

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx